# Custom LabelFor with <figure> in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 application with C# and .NET Framework 4.7.

I want to use this:

```
<input type="file" name="file-5[]" id="file-5" class="inputfile inputfile-4" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple />
<label for="file-5"><figure><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="17" viewBox="0 0 20 17"><path d="M10 0l-5.2 4.9h3.3v5.1h3.8v-5.1h3.3l-5.2-4.9zm9.3 11.5l-3.2-2.1h-2l3.4 2.6h-3.5c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.1l-.8 2.3h-6l-.8-2.2c-.1-.1-.1-.2-.2-.2h-3.6l3.4-2.6h-2l-3.2 2.1c-.4.3-.7 1-.6 1.5l.6 3.1c.1.5.7.9 1.2.9h16.3c.6 0 1.1-.4 1.3-.9l.6-3.1c.1-.5-.2-1.2-.7-1.5z"/></svg></figure> <span>Chose file&hellip;</span></label>
```

With this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.File)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File)
```

I have tried the following but it isn't correct in the `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.File)`:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.File, {
                   "<figure><svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='20' height='17' viewBox='0 0 20 17'><path d='M10 0l-5.2 4.9h3.3v5.1h3.8v-5.1h3.3l-5.2-4.9zm9.3 11.5l-3.2-2.1h-2l3.4 2.6h-3.5c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.1l-.8 2.3h-6l-.8-2.2c-.1-.1-.1-.2-.2-.2h-3.6l3.4-2.6h-2l-3.2 2.1c-.4.3-.7 1-.6 1.5l.6 3.1c.1.5.7.9 1.2.9h16.3c.6 0 1.1-.4 1.3-.9l.6-3.1c.1-.5-.2-1.2-.7-1.5z'/></svg></figure> <span>Chose file&hellip;</span>"
               })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file", @class = "inputfile inputfile-4", data_multiple_caption = "{count} files selected" })
```

The problem is with the `<figure><svg...`.

I have also tried to change it the id here:

```
<input type="file" name="file-5[]" id="File"
```

But in the controller I receive the `File` field as null.

What do I have to do to get the File in the controller and the label showing `<figure><svg...`?

Comment: Your code has a syntax error

Comment: @AluanHaddad You've missed to say: "guest where..."

Comment: Is your problem the label not displaying correctly, of your file property not getting a value when posted to your action? For the first you could do ```<label for="@Html.IdFor(m => m.File)">....```, bypassing the LabelFor handler. As for your model not getting filled in the action. Are you sure the data is send to the server? What does your model/action look like (more specifically, how do you try to access the posted files?).

Comment: You cannot use `LabelFor()` in your case - that method generates a `<label>text</label>` only (the text will be encoded). You need to create you own custom extension method (or generate it manually)

Comment: As for the file input, if the the property is `HttpPostedFileBase File` then the it must be `name="File"` (which your `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, ...)` generated correctly